# Is it possible to make an array with QLists inside?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a 2d-array with a size of 2 x ??? so I thought I'd just use a QList like this:

```
QList<MyClass*> arrayname[2];
```

But though the autofill seems to recognize this how I thought it would work, when I try to do something like

```
arrayname[1].append(MyClassPointer);
```

I get an error since it thinks I'm already accessing an element in the list and not the list itself. Do they just not mix well?

I can neither do an array like `arrayname[2][???]` since of course I don't know the second dimension but making a nested list like `QList<QList<MyClass*>>` is just useless overkill to me since I know I'll only ever need two specific elements of the outer QList. For now I've resulted to just making two different lists `QList<MyClass*> list1` and `QList<MyClass*> list2` but this results in too many double code lines.

Comment: *But though the autofill seems* -- You shouldn't learn C++ by what "autofill" does or does not do.

Comment: "I get an error" What error?

Comment: Of course you can do that. You just have to get the syntax correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code was correct and works,

```
QList<MyClass*> arrayname[2];
arrayname[1].append(MyClassPointer);
```

is the correct syntax.

The problem I was having resulted from not checking my copy/paste game and ending up calling `arraynameE[1].append(MyClassPointer);`, an array with a very similar name which doesn't hold a QList, thus no append can be called.